# Partitions per month from the bigquery CLI in python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, gcloud

I'm trying to use partitions per month from the bigquery CLI in python, but the only thing I get is the error in the image

[image]

```
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schema)
table.time_partitioning = bigquery.TimePartitioning(
                    type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.MONTH,
                    field='field_partition')
```

I tried partitions per day and it worked but when trying months it doesn't work
References: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.table.TimePartitioning
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it works well with `MONTH` partition :

```py
def create_table_time_partitioning_month(self):
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    client = bigquery.Client()
    project = client.project
    dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, 'my_dataset')

    table_ref = dataset_ref.table("my_partitioned_table")
    schema = [
       bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
       bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
       bigquery.SchemaField("date", "DATE"),
    ]
    table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schema)
    table.time_partitioning = bigquery.TimePartitioning(
       type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.MONTH,
       field="date"
    )

    table = client.create_table(table)

    print(
       "Created table {}, partitioned on column {}".format(
       table.table_id, table.time_partitioning.field
       )
    )
```

I used the following import :

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

Also, check if you have the correct `Python` [package](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/) installed in your image :

requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-bigquery==3.4.0
```

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```